# Apach Beam / Dataflow transform advice

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a batch data parsing job where the inputs is a list of zip files and each zip file has numerous small text files to parse. In the order of 100Gb compressed across 50 zip files, each zip has 1 million text files.

I am using Apache Beam's package in Python and running the job through Dataflow.

I wrote it as

1. **Create** collection from the list of zip file paths
2. **FlatMap** with a function that yields for every text file inside the zip (one output is a bytes string for all the bytes read from the text file)
3. **ParDo** with a method that yields for every row in the data from the text file / bytes read
4. ...do other stuff like insert each row in the relevant table of some database

I notice this is too slow - CPU resources are only a few % utilised. I suspect that each node is getting a zip file, but work is not distributed among local CPUs - so it's just one CPU working per node. I don't understand why that is the case considering I used FlatMap.

Answer (score 0):

The Dataflow runner makes use of [Fusion optimisation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization):

*'...Such optimizations can include fusing multiple steps or transforms in your pipeline's execution graph into single steps.*'

If you have a transform which in its DoFn has a large fan-out, which I suspect the Create transform in your description does, then you may want to manually break fusion by introducing a shuffle stage to your pipeline as described in the linked documentation.

Comment: Thank you, learning about Beam! What do you think about using a third party package to stream the zip files? The core issue here is that Beam does not support distributed reading of the files inside the archive which is stored on the cloud file system. However, tools like Dask can stream compressed data from GCS. But I am not sure how useful that is - I assume Dataflow wouldn't give worker resources to Dask...

Comment: What about decompressing a zip file locally on each node, then distribute the many decompressed files? That may allow for the wide graph we want.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, this is a two stage DAG. First stage is unzip of 50 2 Gig files. With each output 1M elements. If I recall , you should be able to make use of a SeekableByteChannel with the GSCutil in your first transform to extract the elements. 
So create a KV<somehash,yourzipfiles> and do a reshuffle, which will spread the unzip work around. From the unzip work output KV<somehash,bytes> where bytes is your text file. Use somehash so as not to create a unique key per file, which would be 50m keys.